# Komodo Edit - Autocomplete filling script tag with wrong attributes

Tags: komodoedit

I am using Komodo Edit 8.0. Whenever I add a `<script>` tag, it fills my tag in with

```
<script type="application/x-javascript"><!CDATA[

//]]>
```

How would one change what Komodo fills in for the script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komodo dev here, this is because "script" triggers an auto-abbreviation. Which is a snippet in your toolbox with the name "script" which has the "Auto-Abbreviation" toggle enabled. Please have a look at the Snippets documentation: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/snippets.html

You can turn this off either specifically for "script" by toggling the "Auto-Abbreviation" checkbox or globally by toggling "Enable Auto-Abbreviations" under Preferences > Editor > Smart Editing, in this same area you can also change what would trigger these auto-abbreviations. For example I have it configured to only trigger on "\t" (TAB) so that can press TAB to trigger an abbreviation.